# Sofware for recording video conference, one file per participant

Tags: video-editing, screen-recording, video-conferencing, video-recording

I need a video conference app (free if possible) to do series of video conferences (interviews) and record it on the hard drive of the interviewer.

- The hard part: Each participant video feed/stream must be saved on separate files. This is for later video editing. For example, if it's a 1 on 1 conference, it should save 2 (or more) files: One for the interviewer and one for the interviewee.
- Audio files can be separatly or not. I don't mind meanwhile they are the proper audio streams of each video.
- MP4 compression would be nice, but not mandatory.

I already have tried Zoom but it does one single file of all the conference.

Windows is prefered. But I could run a Linux distro if the software meet my needs.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

[Janus Gateway](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) supports capturing and saving individual audio and video streams at the server.

Janus is not a turn-key solution, it is a backend service requiring a web frontend.

I am unaware of any frontend that exposes the Janus stream saving features as a nice user-friendly web interface.
What exists are a few simpler video conferencing frontends, most notably [Jangouts](https://github.com/jangouts/jangouts), and command-line based tools to convert stream dumps to standards-format media files.

Janus supports all common WebRTC video formats - both the proprietary X.264 and X.265, and free VP8 and VP9.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it, but it looks like Zencastr does [separate recording](https://support.zencastr.com/en/articles/5452702-how-zencastr-records) for each participant. It also appears to record locally for each participant so supposedly you don't get as much drop-out due to network issues for your remote participants.